# How google map track user location all the time even if app is closed and not running in background?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-location, currentlocation

In google iOS app, your timeline shows all the location tracked by google map, even if your app is closed.
Any idea, how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

When app is closed and not running in background then location never track in iOS 11.

**Changes to location tracking in iOS 11**

iOS 11 also makes some major changes to existing APIs. One of the affected areas is location tracking. **If your app only uses location while the app is in the foreground**, as most apps do, you might not have to change anything at all; however, if it’s one of those apps that continuously track user’s location throughout the day, you should probably book some time this summer for making some changes in how you do the tracking and testing possible usage scenarios.

follow this link: https://mackuba.eu/2017/07/13/changes-to-location-tracking-in-ios-11/

Hope will helpful to you!!